# String function in Python

Tags: python

The code below determines if `c` is a palindrome. I was just wondering how `int(str(c)[::-1]) == c` works, as I am new to Python and have not been able to find any information on this.

```
def is_pal(c):
    return int(str(c)[::-1]) == c
```

Comment: What part of it don't you understand? Have you tried out the various bits of it in a Python interpreter prompt? The `[::-1]` is slice notation; it slices from start to end and uses a negative step to produce a *reversed* copy; that part is a duplicate though.

Comment: Your function doesn't work: is_pal("aabbaa") => ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'aabbaa'
Because of the extra int(). Why do you need to convert it to int ?

Comment: That's the canonical post, [this search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22%5B%3A%3A-1%5D%22+%5Bpython%5D+is%3Aq) lists the many duplicates.

Comment: @Grapsus: it works just fine for *integers*. `is_pal(12321)` returns `True`.

Comment: Ok, my bad. Who calls an integer c ?!

Comment: minimal search in web would resolve ur doubt.Duplication never earn u reputation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[::-1]` is in the form of the `[start:end:step]` syntax. When you don't specify the start and end, it works with the whole string. When you specify step as `-1`, it reverses the string and compares whether the reversed string is the same as the original.

#### Examples

```
>>> s = 'hello'
>>> s[1:4]
ell
>>> s[:]
hello
>>> s[::2]
hlo
>>> s[::-1]
olleh

>>> s = 'racecar'
>>> s[::-1]
'racecar'
>>> s == s[::-1]
True
```

Comment: +1 for answer, ur enthusiasm to answer in SO

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your program like this.

```
def is_pal(c):
    A = str(c)  #Python builtin "str" function
    B = A[::-1] #Python "slice"
    C = int(B)  #Python builtin "int" function
    D = C == c  #Python "==" operator
    return D
```